# Fabfiles With Command Line Arguments

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a clean way to have your fabfile take command line arguments?  I'm writing an installation script for a tool that I want to be able to specify an optional target directory via the command line.

I wrote some code to test what would happen if I passed in some command line arguments:

```
# fabfile.py
import sys

def install():
    _get_options()

def _get_options():
    print repr(sys.argv[1:])
```

A couple of runs:

```
$ fab install
['install']

Done.
$ fab install --electric-boogaloo
Usage: fab [options] <command>[:arg1,arg2=val2,host=foo,hosts='h1;h2',...] ...

fab: error: no such option: --electric-boogaloo
```

Comment: I just reread the fabric documentation and found mention of per-task arguments, perhaps this is my best bet? http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the per-task arguments.  It seems like a better idea than doing unattached command line arguments.